# Как отобразить картинку без квадратиков(прозрачного фона)?

Tags: html, css

Как можно отобразить картинку, что б не было квадратиков прозрачного фона , как, например здесь?
https://wapp-dev.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/1581588097410_audi.png

Comment: закинуть в канвас, пройтись по пиксель дате и пиксели которые имеют цвет квадрата заменить на белый, если конкретно нужно убрать эти квадраты и нет возможности попросить диза вырезать картинку)

Comment: @"Lieutenant Jim Dangle" а если файлы грузятся из сервера и должны отобразится в браузере и их количество 2 миллиона?

Comment: тогда сделать blendMode на конкретные цвета и накидывать на картинки, если нужно убрать только такие квадраты, или же брать участки изображения в ширину квадрата и проверять на наличие пикселя поверх ложа блендмод

Comment: если это в браузере, то почему нельзя сделать подложку? и вставить картинку как `img`...квадратиков не будет тогда..

Answer (score 1):

Большая вероятность что формат картинки должен быть .png
Если картинка точно "прозрачноя" квадратиков не будет. 
Jpg вормат - непрозрачен.